# ¿Como separo una linea de texto y la almaceno en un vector en Java?

Tags: java, split, array

Tengo un archivo de texto, el cual es leído y almacenado en una variable `linea`, después separo el contenido de la línea con `linea.split();`. ¿Cómo hago para que el contenido se almacene en un vector, estando ya separado?

Por ejemplo:

***4 1 H 6 O 3 H 5 O*** - separo esta linea con `linea.split();`, ¿Cómo hago para que cada dato de esa linea, se almacene en un vector?

Update: 
Quisiera que el vector quedara [4, 1, H, 6, O, 3, H, 5, O]

Comment: Por favor añade tu código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Por favor muestra un ejemplo de tu resultado. Sigo sin entender si quieres `[4, 1H, 6O, 3H, 5O] o [[4], [1H], [6O], [3H], [5O]]` o `[[4], [1H, 6O, 3H, 5O]]` u otra combinación.

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

[String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) ya devuelve un array de Strings. Y Puedes usar la expresión regular `\s+` para también considerar cuando hay más de un espacio entre las palabras o separadas por tabs.

Para convertirlo en un vector de strings puedes usar un [constructor de Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector(java.util.Collection)) y el método [estático asList de Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)).

```
String linea = "4 1 H 6 O 3 H 5 O";
String[] palabras = linea.split("\\s+");
Vector<String> vectorPalabras = new Vector(Arrays.asList(palabras));
```

Aunque, en general, es preferible tratar la colección a través de un interfaz como List pues esto hace el código más genérico, reutilizable y fácil de refactorizar si fuese necesario. [Y se desaconseja usar Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) (enlace en inglés).

```
List<String> vectorPalabras = Arrays.asList(palabras);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. lo probaré.

Answer (score 2):

> Quisiera que el vector quedara [4, 1, H, 6, O, 3, H, 5, O]

Existen varias formas para poder realizar esto, usando `RegEx` mediante `split()` por ejemplo, usando  `Pattern.compile(" ")` como RegEx:

```
 String linea = "4 1 H 6 O 3 H 5 O";          
 Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
 String[] letras = SPACE.split(linea); 
 //Al generar un Array convertimos a vector
 Vector<String> vectorLetras = new Vector(Arrays.asList(letras));
```

---

esta es otra forma usando el RegEx `"\\s+"` :

```
String linea = "4 1 H 6 O 3 H 5 O";
String[] letras = linea.split("\\s+");
//Al generar un Array convertimos a vector
Vector<String> vectorLetras = new Vector(Arrays.asList(letras));
```

---

Incluso usando [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

```
String linea = "4 1 H 6 O 3 H 5 O";            
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(linea, " ");
String[] letras = new String[tokens.countTokens()];
int index = 0;
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
   letras[index] = tokens.nextToken();
   ++index;
}

//Al generar un Array convertimos a vector
Vector<String> vectorLetras = new Vector(Arrays.asList(letras));
```

---

En los 3 casos obtendrías tu vector de la forma:

```
[4, 1, H, 6, O, 3, H, 5, O]
```

puedes comprobarlo imprimiendo los valores guardados en el vector mediante:

```
 String [] s = vectorLetras.toArray(new String[vectorLetras.size()]);
  for(String elemento: s){
     System.out.println("letra: " + elemento);
  }
```